# Use Ping.SendAsync like the command "ping -t"

Tags: c#, ping

I am trying to ping a host with ping.SendAsync.
Right now i use visual studio 2010 and .net 4
I would like to ping  the specified host until i force stop ping.SendAsync.
The desired result is like when i use the command

`ping -t host`

Right now I learn using the example here:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144962%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

But I can't find how to do it.

```
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.NetworkInformation;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
 public static void AsyncComplexLocalPing ()
    {
        // Get an object that will block the main thread.
        AutoResetEvent waiter = new AutoResetEvent (false);

        // Ping's the local machine.
        Ping pingSender = new Ping ();

        // When the PingCompleted event is raised, 
        // the PingCompletedCallback method is called.
        pingSender.PingCompleted += new PingCompletedEventHandler (PingCompletedCallback);

        IPAddress address = IPAddress.Loopback;

        // Create a buffer of 32 bytes of data to be transmitted. 
        string data = "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa";
        byte[] buffer = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes (data);

        // Wait 10 seconds for a reply. 
        int timeout = 10000;

        // Set options for transmission: 
        // The data can go through 64 gateways or routers 
        // before it is destroyed, and the data packet 
        // cannot be fragmented.
        PingOptions options = new PingOptions (64, true);

        // Send the ping asynchronously. 
        // Use the waiter as the user token. 
        // When the callback completes, it can wake up this thread.
        pingSender.SendAsync (address, timeout, buffer, options, waiter);

        // Prevent this example application from ending. 
        // A real application should do something useful 
        // when possible.
        waiter.WaitOne ();
        Console.WriteLine ("Ping example completed.");
    }
```

Could anyone give me a good tip on how to make the ping.sendasynk keep sending the packets untill i kill the program/or i press a key/or a timer terminates it? Should i just loop the commands? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score -1):

If you don't need to worry about running the query asynchronously, you can consider using `.ContinueWith()` and `.Wait()` and putting the ping method in a loop. This will make the asynchronous method behave like a synchronous call. Pseudocode:

```
        while(looping)
          {
            pingSender.SendAsync(params).ContinueWith((pingTask) =>
            {
                var responseMessage = pingTask.Result;
                if (goodResponse)
                {
                  doSomething
                }
            }).Wait(timeout);
          }
```